# HTTP PUT for new file creation and directory creation

Tags: http, post, directory, put

How would a HTTP Server differentiate whether the request in PUT is for a folder creation or a file creation in a directory.

For HTTP GET what I understood is, if the URL has a trailing /, then HTTP Server looks out for a folder with that name and, if does not exist can look out for a file.

How does this work for PUT for a new file and folder creation?

Comment: It really depends on the particular HTTP server you're using and how it's programmed. In general it's up to the backend server to decide how to handle each request. If you're programming the backend of a web application it's your job to tell the server how to respond.

What sort of HTTP server are you using?

Comment: we are  implementing a new HTTP Server and would like to know the best practice or standard procedure for such conditions

Answer (score 1):

HTTP (the protocol) doesn't have any concept of files or folders. URIs are opaque, except when a relative URI reference is resolved against a base URI.

If you want your server to provide file/folder services, you may want to look into WebDAV (RFC 4918).